# How to run Flutter integration tests as native Android instrumentation tests locally?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, mobile, integration-testing

I have a bunch of integration tests (made as widget tests) in my Flutter app. I would like to run them as native Android tests locally. The problem is I don't understand how to run them.

**My steps:**

1. Simply run flutter integration tests which are located in the root of the project in integration_test folder and check all tests are passing.

```
flutter test integration_test
```

2. Build Android debug apk

```
flutter build apk --debug
```

3. Create Android test apks

```
./gradlew app:assembleAndroidTest
./gradlew app:assembleDebug -Ptarget="./integration_test/app_test.dart"
```

where `"./integration_test/app_test.dart"` is the path to integration tests file

4. ???

**My question:**

What to do next in 4th step in order to run the native Android tests using the connected android emulator?